# How Lightning Network sends payments

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-rfc

I am quite new to the whole blockchain space in general and was reading about Lightning Network. In LN which message type is used to encode payment information? For example, in the below book, there are references to 7 different messages exchanged between channel partners.

https://github.com/lnbook/lnbook/blob/develop/07_payment_channels.asciidoc

But none of them seem to transfer information about payments; something like "Bob, I am sending you 10 sats"

I also looked at the Bolt specification repo on GitHub but was not able to locate this. Is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The `update_add_htlc` message transports the `onion` with payment / routing information. The information itself is desced in the onion routing chapter that explains how nodes can handle this